# How to log an c++ exception

Tags: c++, exception

Do you know how can I log the exception ?
right now the message in the catch statement is printed, but i cannot understood why ins´t Manage.Gere() called sussefully .

```
try{
    Manager.Gere(&par,&Acc, coman, comando, RunComando, log, &parti, comandosS, RunComandosSuper,true);
}
catch (...)
{
    log("ERROR ENTER GERE*****");
}


Perif::Gere(CString *par, CString *Acc, HANDLE coman, HANDLE comando, HANDLE RunComando, Log &log, CString *parti, HANDLE comandosS, HANDLE RunComandosSuper,bool first)
{
    log->LogD("Perif :: Gere Enter****** "); //It doesnt get printed

}
```

Comment: Can you please try to add more information on what you want to achieve?  Do you want to write the exception to a log (on unix, windows?) or do you want to understand why the method fails/does not fail?

Comment: want to understand why the method fails, could be a  problem with its params?

Comment: Make both functions use the same logging code. log() and log->logD() may be working differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need there is find which exceptions `Manage.Gere` can throw.
Then `catch` them specifically like `catch(FirstExceptionGereThrows &exc)` and when you catch all possible exceptions, you'll know what is failing in `Manage.Gere`.

```
catch(FirstException &exc){
   log << "Failed because FirstException\n";
}catch(SecondException &exc){
   log << "Failed because SecondException\n";
}
```

After, and if you are lucky enough the exceptions thrown by `Manage.Gere` may include some extra info about the crash which you could log as well.

```
catch(FirstException &exc){
   log << "Failed because FirstException: " << exc.what() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: How can i find which exceptions Manage.Gere can throw ?

Tks

Comment: Documentation or looking into Manage.Gere code, there is no other way.

Comment: If the exceptions are derived from std::exception, there is no absolute need to catch them specifically - just catch std::exception, and examine its what() member.

Comment: Logic says most of them should derive from std::exception, but my experience says they rarely are, at least the libs I use.

Answer (score 3):

A well-behaved API should only throw objects of types derived from `std::exception`. If that's the case, then the exception will have a member function `const char *what()` containing a message, which will hopefully describe the error. So you could try this, and hope that it helps:

```
try {
    Manage.Gere(...);
} catch (const std::exception &e) {
    log(e.what());
} catch (...) {
    log("Manage.Gere threw unknown exception");
}
```

If it throws a type that isn't a `std::exception`, then you will need to look at the documentation and/or source for the function to see what could go wrong, and what types it does throw. If none of this is available, I would be looking for a better library.

Comment: just tried your code and in the log showed "Manage.Gere threw unknown exception"

Comment: Then whatever was thrown wasn't a subclass of `std::exception`... maybe it's a user-defined or library-defined class or a basic type like `const char*`?

Comment: It might be worth adding handlers for `const char*` and `const std::string&`, as Neil suggests in his answer, and also `const CString&` (which I assume is another string class). If that doesn't help, then the only option is to read the documentation/source for the function.

Comment: And maybe `const CString*`, in case the API is truly evil.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, RTFM is really the answer. However, I've found that lazy programmers often write code like:

```
if ( something ) {
   throw "Something has happened!";
}
```

so it is always worthwhile trying to catch both const char * ans std::string:

```
try {
   // stuff
}
catch( const char * s ) {
    cerr << s << endl;
}
catch( const std::string & s ) {
    cerr << s << endl;
}
// other catches here
```

Comment: In addition to strings I find lots of 'throw int(errorCode)' so it is worth trying to catch these as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my tool as an external debugger which catches C++ exceptions and automatically create minidump files for offline debugging. See http://alax.info/blog/1211 for details.

The good thing is that you don't need any code for this, or you can even debug an application which you don't have code for, or you cannot rebuild it for any reason. The dump file will get you stacks and information, and the application will be able to continue execution.